# checkbox for all item

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have the following code. this works only for one row. I want this should work for all rows & also if I select the top checkbox, then it should select all the checkboxes to show all items in the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Quotation New Design</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" >
            function valueChanged()
            {
                if($(".checkezspeedkit").is(":checked"))   
                    $(".qtyezspeedkit ").show();
                else
                    $(".qtyezspeedkit").hide();
            }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
            .qtyezspeedkit {
            display:none;
            }
            .optionezspeedkit{
            display:none;
            }
            .qtyezspeedkitbluetooth{
            display:none;
            }
            .optionezspeedkitbluetooth{
            display:none;
            }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4>Checkbox Test</h4>
        <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
                   <thead>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Option</th>
                   </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezspeedkit" name="chkezspeedkit" onchange="valueChanged()"/></td>
                    <td>EZSpeed Kit</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezspeedkit" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="qtyezspeedkit">
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezspeedkitbluetooth" name="chkezspeedkitbluetooth" onchange="valueChanged()"/></td>
                    <td>EZSpeed Kit - Bluetooth</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="optionezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>           
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezspeedkitwifi" name="chkezspeedkitbluetooth" onchange="valueChanged()"/></td>
                    <td>EZSpeed Kit - Wi-Fi</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="optionezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezenergykit" name="chkezspeedkitbluetooth" onchange="valueChanged()"/></td>
                    <td>EZEnergy Kit</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="optionezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>               
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezenergykitbluetooth" name="chkezspeedkitbluetooth" onchange="valueChanged()"/></td>
                    <td>EZEnergy Kit - Bluetooth</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="optionezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezenergykitwifi" name="chkezspeedkitbluetooth" onchange="valueChanged()"/></td>
                    <td>EZEnergy Kit - Wi-Fi</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="optionezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure how this is PHP related...

Answer (score 1):

This function check all the item with the class "checkboxitem".
   if val is true jquery will set the attr "checked" to true on all the checkbox with the class or set to false if "val" is false.

```
 function check_all(val){
                if(val){
                    $(".checkboxitem").attr("checked", true);
                }else{
                    $(".checkboxitem").attr("checked", false);
                }
            }
```

Also if you want it to be more generic you can do :

```
function check_all(val,class_to_check = "checkboxitem"){
                    if(val){
                        $("."+class_to_check).attr("checked", true);
                    }else{
                        $("."+class_to_check).attr("checked", false);
                    }
                }
```

Where "class_to_check" is set if empty. 
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by assigning a special class to each of the checkboxes.  In my case I assigned "checkboxitem".  Then I created some JavaScript code which uses jQuery to assign the checked property of each of the elements which have the class assigned.

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/t7tpzoku/

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4>Checkbox Test</h4>
        <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
                   <thead>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Option</th>
                   </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezspeedkit checkboxitem" name="chkezspeedkit" /></td>
                    <td>EZSpeed Kit</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezspeedkit" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="qtyezspeedkit">
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezspeedkitbluetooth checkboxitem" name="chkezspeedkitbluetooth" /></td>
                    <td>EZSpeed Kit - Bluetooth</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="optionezspeedkitbluetooth" >
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>           
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezspeedkitwifi checkboxitem" name="chkezspeedkitbluetooth" /></td>
                    <td>EZSpeed Kit - Wi-Fi</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezspeedkitwifi" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="optionezspeedkitwifi" >
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezenergykit checkboxitem" name="chkezspeedkitbluetooth" /></td>
                    <td>EZEnergy Kit</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezenergykit" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="optionezenergykit" >
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>               
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezenergykitbluetooth checkboxitem" name="chkezspeedkitbluetooth" /></td>
                    <td>EZEnergy Kit - Bluetooth</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezenergykitbluetooth" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="optionezenergykitbluetooth" >
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkezenergykitwifi checkboxitem" name="chkezspeedkitbluetooth" /></td>
                    <td>EZEnergy Kit - Wi-Fi</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select1" style="width: 50px" class="qtyezenergykitwifi" >
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Select2" style="width: 137px" class="optionezenergykitwifi" >
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option>Required</option>
                            <option>Option</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function()
{
 $("#checkall").on("click", function()
 {
  $(".checkboxitem").prop("checked", $("#checkall").prop("checked"));
  $( ".checkboxitem" ).trigger( "change" );
 });

 $(".checkboxitem").on("change", function()
 {
  var className1 = "." + $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0].replace("check", "qty");
  var className2 = "." + $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0].replace("check", "option");  
                if($(this).is(":checked"))   
                {
                    $(className1).show();
                    $(className2).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    $(className1).hide();
                    $(className2).hide();
                }
 });
});
```

Comment: @shumonira: I updated my answer.  Firstly, I didn't 100% understand your issue because it wasn't very clear.  Secondly, you issues with using the same CSS class for each drop down list.  Once I fixed all of the issues I think the jsfiddle is what you are looking for now.  If not, please clarify to what you are trying to do.